# Write all these if statements cleaner

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

i have an issue where, when i go to add more "names" to the if statements. Its hard for me to see if there all ready on there. Thus is there a more clean way to write this Where i can easly see what names are all read there?

```
    function TfDB.GetW(name: string) :integer;
  begin
     result := 0;
    if (name = 'Destacker') or (name='Router') or (name = 'Turn Table') Then
        result := 57;
    if (name = 'Laser Marker') then
        result := 66;
    if (name = 'SP28')OR(name='Chamber') OR (name = 'CM402') OR (name = 'SP60') then
        result := 65;
    if (name = 'Conveyor') OR (name = 'Slide Gate') OR (name = 'Washer') then
        result := 51;
    if (name = 'BTU') OR (name = 'Furukawa') OR (name = 'Radial') OR (name = 'HDP') or (name = 'MSR') OR (name = 'Koki') Or (name = 'MSF') then
        result := 98;
    if (name = 'Buffer')OR (name = 'Reclaimer') OR (name = 'ECO Roller') then
        result := 49;
    if (name = 'Inverter') or (name = 'CNC') then
        result := 42;
    if (name = '3-D Check Station') or (name='Screw Machine') or (name='VT-Win') or(name='Component Viewer') then
        result := 58;
    if (name = 'AOI Panel') or (name='AirBlow') then
        result := 42;
    if (name='Mag Loader') or (name='Soltec') then
        result := 73;
    if (name='Tester') then
        result := 33;
    if (name='LoadBox') then
        result := 17;
    if (name = 'DeltaWave') then
        result := 89;
    if (name = 'ScrewFeeder') then
        result := 25;
    if (name='Pump') then
        result := 33;

    //if result is 0 show message error.

  end;
```

Comment: I think you should use a DB or at least an INI in order to be editable in the future, hardcoding may not be a good idea.

Comment: It is using a db,  it grabs the name of a machine (Pump) and gives it a shape size of 33.. But yes if i ever wanted to change the size of a machine or add new machine sizes then i woudl have to change. but just found this easier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a dictionary, `TDictionary<string, Integer>`, and store it in a global variable. Load it up with the name to width mapping at initialization time. And then your function becomes a one-liner.

```
var
  WidthMapping: TDictionary<string, Integer>;
....
function TfDB.GetW(name: string) :integer;   
begin
  if not WidthMapping.TryGetValue(name, Result) then
    ... handle error condition
end;
....
initialization
  WidthMapping := TDictionary<string, Integer>.Create;
  WidthMapping.Add('Destacker', 57);
  WidthMapping.Add('Router', 57);
  ... etc.
....
finalization
  WidthMapping.Free;
```

Comment: I like this approach and keeps it stacked easy for me to read

Comment: may i ask, what is the uses needed for TDictionary?

Comment: It's `Generics.Collections`, or if you are using the new namespaces, `System.Generics.Collections`. For future reference, you can always look this up in the online help: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary

Comment: thanks, i keep putting generics, and collections...just not together.

Comment: I wonder ,  can you make it simple and have logic here like with widthmapping ...  beign  Add('name'1); Add('nameA'2);   or even a way like Widthmapping.add('Destacker':'Router':'Turntable', 57);  ?

Comment: You can certainly use a `with` statement and then a list of `Add` method calls.

Comment: ah great , was not sure with it being in the initialization area.. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Yes, don't use an `if` statement but an array and a loop:

```
const
  NAME_RESULT: array [1..2] of record
    Name: string;
    Value: Integer;
  end = (
    (Name: 'whatever'; Value: 57)
  , (Name: 'Something else'; Value: 57)
  );
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0; // or whatever you need your default to be
  for i := Low(NAME_RESULT) to High(NAME_RESULT) do
    if SameText(name, NAME_RESULT[i].Name) then
    begin
      Result := NAME_RESULT[i].Value;
      Break;
    end;
end;
```

Additional advantage: you don't need to keep the names which return the same values together but can sort the list alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array (or dynamic array if you want to further add more names without any concerns of the array dimensions) of strings that contains all the names you want to test for (here I assumed fixed size string array):

```
    var test = array [1..50] of string;
    a[1]:='Destacker';
    a[2]:='Router';
```

etc.

In your test routine you may use the *case* keyword like this:

```
    function TfDB.GetW(index: integer) :integer
    begin
     result:=0;
     case index of
      1,2,3: result:=57;
      4: result:=66
     end
    end;
```

I think it's easier this way

Comment: How do you get from the control name to an index? And please don't call an index variable name. Any variable called name should be a string.

Comment: Sorry, I must have skipped that part :)